# Kafka producer client is not able to connect to schema registry

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to run a job on google Dataproc which pushes a record into a Kafka topic. It uses a schema registry for schema validation and serialization. Representative code below:

```scala
case class KafkaProducerExample(envConfig: Config, isLocal: Boolean) {

  @transient
  lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(classOf[KafkaProducerExample])

  def test_send(): Unit= {

    val srAuth = envConfig.Kafka.schemaRegAuthInfo

    val schemaRegistryServer: String = if (isLocal) "http://localhost:8081" else
      envConfig.Kafka.registry

    val schemaUrl = s"$schemaRegistryServer/subjects/topic_name-value/versions/1"
    println(schemaUrl)
    val apiKey = srAuth.get.split(":")(0)
    val apiSecret = srAuth.get.split(":")(1)

    // Set up the request headers with Confluent Cloud credentials
    val headers_1 = Map(
      "Content-Type" -> "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"
    )

    // Send a GET request to retrieve the schema
    val response = requests.get(schemaUrl, auth = Tuple2(apiKey, apiSecret), headers = headers_1, verifySslCerts = false)

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      val schema = response.text()
      println("Retrieved schema:")
      println(schema)
    } else {
      println(s"Failed to retrieve schema. Status code: ${response.statusCode}")
      println(response.text())
    }

    val kafkaProps = config.loadKafkaProducerProperties(envConfig, logger, isLocal)
    // Replace with your Kafka topic
    val topic = "topic_name"

    // SomeClass is an avro generated case class
    val bre_form_record = SomeClass(id = "123",
      batch_id = "123"
    )

    // Create Kafka producer
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, GenericRecord](kafkaProps)

    val avroRecord = new org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record(SomeClass.SCHEMA$)
    avroRecord.put("id", "123")
    avroRecord.put("batch_id", "123")
  

    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, GenericRecord](topic, "key", avroRecord)

    producer.send(record)
    producer.close()
  }
}
```

Now the GET request works and I am able to get a response from the Schema Registry. But the kafka producer client gives me the following error (truncated):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema{"type":"record","name"
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401
```

Following are the relevant libraries in build.sbt:

```
 "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "3.4.0",
 "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.11.0",
 "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "7.1.1
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: 401 means, as the error says, that you're not authorized. If I'm reading correctly, you're not providing credentials to your Kafka Producer.

Comment: Yes I am providing it to the producer in kafkaprops. I've used the same to get request from the schema registry

Comment: We can't see what your KafkaProps are set to. Also, this isn't Spark code

Comment: So the error was due to the merge strategy used to create the uber-jar. Somehow the right version of the class was not being loaded. It is related to: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1759

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes my mistake, this is part of a larger spark code which I isolated to recreate the bug.

Comment: I've not personally seen this error before, but you could show logs of the SchemaRegistryConfig / AvroConfig sections that get printed when the constructor is called... That'll show what properties are actually loaded. Jar ordering shouldn't matter since kafka-clients doesn't include any Confluent packages and the Confluent packages don't recompile kafka-clients. spark-kafka-sql, on the other hand, does include kafka-clients (but not 3.4.0), but the error here only comes from the avro-serializer / schema-registry-client packages

Comment: We were able to resolve this. So, when we package the jar file we basically discard all the things in meta-inf folders. In the case of the schema registry client library, there are two files there having to do with authentication that the library needs. So we just added a hook to preserve those